# Mathematica GUI menus for packages and interfaces

Tags: user-interface, interface, wolfram-mathematica

I have some packages and interfaces ( .nb) written in Wolfram Mathematica. And I want to put them in one application in the way that some " menu" will call them. It' ll be great to have a help in menu and so on. How can I organize such user interface???

Maybe some of you has such experience, or learned some examples!!

Thanks a lot in anticipation!

Comment: Please give your question a more specific title.

Comment: You might want to review the Mathematica Palette Interface: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CreatingPalettes.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I thought about palettes also, but I'm interested also in some technique to "run" interactive interfaces without displaying code for user,..like .exe. I 've also examined J/Link and . NET a bit, but expect some advices from your own experience.

Comment: This question might fit better on [the Mathematica-specific Stack Exchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) but I would suggest you edit it to be clearer first.

Answer (score 2):

You can add menu commands by adding code like the following to your MenuSetup.tr file in Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows

Make a backup first though!

```
...
  MenuItem["&About Mathematica...", "AboutBoxDialog"]
  }],
  Menu["&Additions", 
  {
    Item["Package &One", KernelExecute[Get["MyPackages`PackageOne`"]], MenuEvaluator->Automatic],
    Delimiter,
    Item["Function &Two", KernelExecute[MyPackages`FunctionTwo[]], MenuEvaluator->Automatic]
  }]
}]
```

In the above example you can call the whole package file PackageOne.m or call just a function. However to call a single function you will need to have loaded the package beforehand, possibly from an init file.

You can also modify the menu on a per session basis using `AddMenuCommands[]` as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5417/running-a-package-automatically-when-its-saved/5418#5418).